# Django: list_filter using a friendly name

Tags: python, django

In my admin.py I filter by 'active' and 'country' this is done using the following line of code within my SomethingAdmin class....

```
 list_filter = ['active', 'countryid']
```

As you can see countryid is not pretty when displayed in my admin list view, how can I change this to a more friendly name, say just 'Country'?

Thanks.

**Update:**
Below seems to work:

```
incentiveid = models.ForeignKey(Incentive,verbose_name="Incentive", 
null=True, db_column='incentiveID', blank=True)
```

Comment: Define labels for your fields in the model. `label='Country'`

Comment: is a fk  models.ForeignKey(Country, null=True, db_column='countryID', blank=True)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [Aamir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/860103/aamir-adnan) says, if you define labels on your fields in your model, you should see the more attractive filter options:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    countryid = models.ForeignKey(Country, 
                                  verbose_name="Country", null=True, 
                                  db_column='countryID', blank=True)
```

assuming that `Country` is name of another `Model` - this should show up in the `Admin` filter view.

Comment: is this the same as verbose_name?

Comment: No, `verbose_name` would be for things like help tags.

Comment: ok so I tried this and it changed the filter to 'Country' are you sure about verbose_name? models.ForeignKey(Country,verbose_name="Country", null=True, db_column='countryID', blank=True)

Comment: Ok, my bad. On `ForeignKey` you do need `verbose_name` - updating answer.